# Date value subtraction producing wrong error

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am using the below code to show the date difference in Day:Hour:Minute format.

```
 Function TimeSpan(dt1, dt2) 

    Dim seconds,minutes,hours,days

    If (isDate(dt1) And IsDate(dt2)) = false Then 
        TimeSpan = "00:00:00" 
        Exit Function 
    End If 

    seconds = Abs(DateDiff("S", dt1, dt2)) 
    minutes = seconds \ 60 
    hours = minutes \ 60 
    days  = hours \ 24
    minutes = minutes mod 60 
    seconds = seconds mod 60 
    days    = days    mod 24 

    if len(hours) = 1 then hours = "0" & hours 

    TimeSpan = days& ":" & _ 
        RIGHT("00" & hours , 2) & ":" & _ 
        RIGHT("00" & minutes, 2) 
End Function
```

But it is not producing expected values for some cases.

```
  D1=#9/24/2012  8:09:15 AM# and D2=#9/25/2012  8:09:15 AM# gives correct data like 1:24:00 whereas below are producing error when working with VBScript and Excel.
  D1=#9/5/2012  8:45:43 AM# and D2=#9/25/2012  8:45:43 AM# result=0.888888888888889
  D1=#9/6/2012  8:29:34 AM# and D2=#9/17/2012  8:59:36 AM# result=0.503125
```

Can you explain why so?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need such a complicated function when the *elapsed time* can be found quite easily? And please confirm, that you are using **VBSCRIPT** or **VBA** which are two different things.

Comment: I am using VBScript Bon... I am not educated with VBA....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my [answer from an earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815538/how-to-get-the-difference-in-minutes-between-two-dates-in-microsoft-excel/13816739#13816739) in your **UDF** as the following: This answer is in **VBA**

**Please declare all variables and force yourself to declare by adding option explicit :)**

```
option explicit
Function TimeSpan(dt1 As Date, dt2 As Date) As String
Dim dtTemp As Date

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        If (IsDate(dt1) And IsDate(dt2)) = False Then
            TimeSpan = "00:00:00"
            Exit Function
        End If

        If dt2 < dt1 Then
            dtTemp = dt2
            dt2 = dt1
            dt1 = dt2
        End If
        '-- since you only had days, I have put up to days here. 
        '-- if you require months, years you may use yy:mm:dd:hh:mm:ss
        '-- which is pretty self-explainatory ;)
        TimeSpan = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text((dt2 - dt1), "dd:hh:mm:ss")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Function
```

UDF Output:

[image]

**But I really suggest you to use Excel sheet functions if you have the freedom and possibility to do so.**

---

### If date difference is more than 31 days

Then use the [solution as per this article](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datedif.aspx)
Incorporate the `DateDiff` to the UDF.

Comment: Can you help me in my below post please... that was really painful for me to implement ? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819708/sparse-matrix-creation-using-vbscript#comment19033369_13819708

Comment: Let me give it a try? But you do understand the concept on the above answer?

Comment: BTW looking at your comments, it seems KB's solution is working for you apart from a minor am/pm issue. Format that into 24 hour format, so you will not get such. Let me know if you still require changing my code into VBScript? :)

Comment: Yes, I am done! with KB's solution.. Please help me on my above mentioned post..Bon... I am really...in middle of the ocean.. My code is too much time taking one...thus taking you guys help to make it optimized one. :-)

Comment: If possible you can advice on KB's code,where you want me to put such 24 hour formatting. :-)

Comment: If you vote me up for the logic, perhaps may be ;) it is as painful as for anyone to try converting into VB Script

Comment: Hi Bon Can you help me in the below post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823912/to-move-the-cell-values-in-a-group-from-right-to-left-if-any-group-of-cells-are/13853950#comment19077100_13853950

Comment: @VBSlover sorry your response to my above answer was very poor. How do you measure people's effort put on you in the first place?

Comment: Sorry for that, today i implemented your code and tested also. it was fine,but forgot to change my vote dear. I am doing it right away.

Comment: This solution will fail when the timespan is more then the number of days in january (31), if that will never happen it is fine, otherwise you better use my code or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware I'm more used to write VBA, so you might need to tweak here and there.

Alternatively you could just subtract the two dates from eachother as numerical value:

```
Dim dblDateDiff as Double
dblDateDiff = Abs(dt2 - dt1)
```

Now the Timespan would be (dont use "d" as that would not include months and years that could have passed):

```
Timespan = Int(dblDateDiff) & ":" & Hour(dblDateDiff) & ":" & Minute(dblDateDiff)
```

If the direction (positive or negative) of the Timespan is relevant you could change the last line into:

```
Timespan = Sgn(dblDateDiff) * Int(dblDateDiff) & ":" & Hour(dblDateDiff) & ":" & Minute(dblDateDiff)
```

For your time formatting issue either:

1. Set the number format of the output cell to Text, or
2. Add a single quote in front of the rest of the string:

   ```
    Timespan = "'" & Sgn(dblDateDiff) * Int(dblDateDiff) & ":" & Hour(dblDateDiff) & ":" & Minute(dblDateDiff)
   ```

Comment: Can you help me in my below post please... that was really painful for me to implement ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819708/sparse-matrix-creation-using-vbscript#comment19033369_13819708

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Is the concept clear for you? If not please let me/us know what is not working. In case an answer provided did work for you then tick the V shaped mark to the left of the answer post (or that of @bonCodigo in case his answer worked for you) so all may know you dont need further assistance with this particular question.

Comment: Yes I have tried your one... And it is producing the output a bit better than previous one. But with the duration i also got the the output as : D1="9/11/2012  1:42:59 AM" and D2="9/4/2012  6:09:15 AM",but the output is : "6:19:33 AM".. I do want that duration part only,not any AM or PM post the duration.Please advice how to remove that.

Comment: I am not understanding your comment, have you applied my script and does that give you this problem (I think that is not possible), or have you got this AM,PM problem with another solution?

Comment: Yes, I tried your one. In my spreadsheet the result is showing AM Or PM with the correct durations...

Comment: What could happen is that Excel "thinks" the answer day:hour:minute is actually hour:minute:second, to avoid this you will have to manually set the number format of the cells you write the answer to Text. Do that BEFORE you actaully write the answer to it as otherwise Excel will already have converted it. Alternatively you could add a single quote at the start of your string, with that Excel will not convert the output to a time value!

Comment: There are 500 columns out of which 300 will be updating by the date function.So manually to change such columns are impossible, as the columns are also not fixed..it is dynamic.  So suggest me in the code where to change if possible. :-)

Comment: if not manually then programmatically. And the coding alterative is in my answer (I updated it 40 minutes ago) at the end.

Comment: Yes...due to browser issue i haven't seen that. Sorry to bother you in that case.:-)

Comment: No problem, if that works for you please mark as answered. Good luck with your other questions as well!

Comment: Yes..Sure I will.Please help me on my another post,as i just pasted here above.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797200/duration-vbscript-vbs-function as an reference